# Google search box within the search results not working

Tags: drupal, seo, search-engine

I Follow Google Tutorial For search box with in google search result just like above screens shot

i added this code on my site

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "WebSite",
"url": "https://www.example.com/",
"potentialAction": {
"@type": "SearchAction",
  "target": "https://www.example.com/search/node/{keys}",
  "query-input": "required name=keys"
 }
 }

  </script>
```

Am I doing something wrong? My site uses Drupal 7.

Comment: You seem to forgot the screenshot, please add more relevant code too (libraries included, HTML, etc.)

Comment: Write me down your website address so i can have a look.

Comment: http://datasoftsindia.com/

Comment: btw wright now i have use this target path
"target": "https://www.example.com/search/{keys}"
i have confused 
"target": "https://www.example.com/search/node/{keys}" OR "target": "https://www.example.com/search/{keys}"

Comment: hello , George Stefas
any change for my site code for sitelink search box plz tell me ....
thanks